# Process Tracking with Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, process, tracking, apex, progress

Is it possible to visualize process tracking with Oracle APEX?
For example for the process "application".

Assuming it is a process with many steps. In this case i would like to divide the process. Accordingly, the process would be divided into sub-processes and this would then be broken down into the individual process steps.
[Sub-Process: Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQeB3.png)

The arrow represents the first sub-process of the entire process.
The lower circles visualize the individual process steps (here I have oriented myself to the Create Page Wizard). When the individual steps of the sub-process have been successfully executed by the various participants in the process, it continues with the second sub-process.
[Second SUb-Process: Assessment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dFwO.png)

It may be important to note that the individual process steps must be performed by several people. For example, in this process there is the applicant, the secretary, and the department manager. The process shown is intended only as an example.

Comment: I don't know if this may be relevant: https://apex.mt-ag.com/en/flowsforapex

Comment: Yes, I have already heard of the tool flows for apex but I'm more wondering if such a visualization of the process is possible in APEX. So especially the subdivision of the whole process into sub-processes and the subdivision of the sub-process into the single process steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a easy way to visualize a process in the latest version of APEX (currently 20.2) without a plug-in, but it does seem that Oracle is planning on adding support for some similar functionality in a future version of APEX.

Looking at the [Roadmap for future version of APEX](https://apex.oracle.com/en/learn/resources/roadmap/), it does look like process modeling is currently planned to be added to the standard release in a future version of APEX.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the update. May I ask which plugins are best suited for such a visualisation?

Comment: As @Tony Andrews had said, MT AG has a plugin available for business process modeling: https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:14556265524208::::P710_PLG_ID:COM.MTAG.APEX.BPMNVIEWER.REGION